# Comparing "Data Values" value in two files in Bash and printing header is "Data Values" doesn't exist

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm writing a small script that connects to a live MySQL database runs 'show databases;' and redirects the output to a file. I then run the same command against a MySQLDump Restore.

Secondly I run through the first list of databases and run

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,SUM(TABLE_ROWS)\
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES\
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$VariableListOFDBFile'\
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;"
```

which outputs the following:

```
provisioning
accounting_log  567
bank_holidays   56
cdr_log 68407
cps_only_order_report_log       55251
error_log       21361
order_report_log        485626
provider        4
request 77463
request_log     67745
retention_code  112
setting 85
```

I do this for both the live and dump.

I then wish to cross-reference both lists of tables and rows (as shown above) - In theory, both files should contain the same lines and the same information.

the pattern goes:

heading ($1)
table_name ($1) value ($2)

Instead of this getting outputted to a file, I wish for the results to be shown on screen like:

Heading: 
table_name value / percentage - Ok/Warning

I'm thinking the way would be to check if $2 exists with AWK (this will give me a heading) and print $1 which is the heading, then move onto checking the values of $2 against $2 and working out a percentage of A to B, if the percentage is > 10 then warn else tell me it's ok.   The data will be different but not by that much as the live database will still be writing.

I really hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add expected output in code tags too.

Comment: _I wish to include this within an IF statement_ ...  IF what?

Comment: I don't see that $2 anywhere except in subject and explanation

Comment: if [ provision = null ]; then find percentage of $2 and $2 and if > 10 print error, else print ok.

Comment: $2 being the numbers in file 1 and file 2

Comment: @ZakHargreaves Please edit your question rather than trying to paste pseudo-code in a comment.

Comment: @ZakHargreaves Also, please include the [smallest possible example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code which causes the problem. (If you want to figure this out without asking random strangers on the internet, you need to find the MCVE, anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution. And no, I have absolutely no idea what that if statement is about. Anyway, this might get you started:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} \
  NR==FNR{if (NF>1) a[$1]=$2;next} \
  NF>1{ b=(a[$1]==0?0:100-$2/(a[$1]/100)); \
        printf("%s%s%s%.2f%\n", $1, OFS, (b>0)?"+":"", b); \
        next}1' file1 file2
provisioning
accounting_log  +24.51%
bank_holidays   +0.00%
cdr_log +0.00%
cps_only_order_report_log   -0.93%
error_log   0.00%
```

EDIT:
So you want some sort of threshold, determining if you should print `error` or `ok`. Take a look at this, using the threshold as a variable:

```
$ awk -v threshold=10 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} \
  NR==FNR{if (NF>1) a[$1]=$2;next} \
  NF>1{ b=(a[$1]==0?0:100-$2/(a[$1]/100)); \
        printf("%s%s%s%.2f%s%s\n", $1, OFS, (b>0)?"+":"", b, OFS, (b>threshold)?"error":"ok"); \
        next}1' file1 file2
provisioning
accounting_log  +24.51  error
bank_holidays   +0.00   ok
cdr_log +0.00   ok
cps_only_order_report_log   -0.93   ok
error_log   0.00    ok
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. That's a big start; I appreciate your answer.  Basically, I wanted to try and incorporate the above into an if-statement line by line to inform if the percentages were higher or lower than 10%.  Im basically checking a live database row table count against a database dump table count to check the data is there. I will work on the above and amend.  Thank you.

Comment: NP. You could do yourself a favor by explaining that awkward if-part of your question. There are some people out there that are glad to help.

Comment: I've amended.  Hopefully it makes sense. By your code above, is there anyway to incorporate a 0 value?

Comment: It runs but gives me this and exists out: erp_reporting
awk: cmd. line:2: (FILENAME=127.0.0.1-dumptables.txt FNR=14) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: Cause: $2 in file1 can be 0.  Change `b=100-$2/(a[$1]/100);` to `b=(a[$1]==0?100:100-$2/(a[$1]/100));`. We can't really define what the percentage growth is, because the first value is 0.

Comment: It's more than likely going to be 0% due to no data within that particular table. In theory the above will print file2 and provide +/-

Comment: Fair enough. Make it `b=(a[$1]==0?0:100-$2/(a[$1]/100));`

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to add a 0.5 sleep before moving onto the next line? Thanks

Comment: Sure. You'll need to add a `system("sleep 0.5")` just before the `printf` statement.

Comment: May I ask why the printf doesn’t inherit my colour codes?